# How can I group data by hour in a specific day in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i want to display a graph of how many visits occur per hour divided per day, in my collection i have objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab111a0646e371568c8cfa0"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-20T13:46:30.018Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

i tried to use the .mapReduce() as specified here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ and something like this:

```
db.getCollection('monitors').mapReduce(function(){emit(this.date);}, function(key,values){return Array(values)}, {query: date:'"2018-03-20T13:46:30.018Z"'}, out:"order_totals"})
```

just to try to collect all the visits in that day but it doesn't work.

Comment: it gives me some errors "command failed" and aggregate failed

Comment: What is your MongoDB version and which query did you run?

Comment: MongoDB 3.4.3-10 and Robo3t 1.2

i run you code and gives me errors like "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.", "code" : 40323, "codeName" " etc..
i delete the last "count":"$sum":1 and it "works". no errors but no results.

Comment: ok now it works but it count only the visits in the day, but i also have to group every visit per every hour of every day